# How to make a result from function to show in another activity

Tags: android

```
public void doSomething(View view) {
    String url, link_url, pro;

    url = textIn.getText().toString();
    pro = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
    c1 = new ConnectInternetClass(this);

    if (!url.isEmpty()) {
        if (url.contains(".") && !(url.contains(" "))) {
            if (url.split("\\.").length > 1) {
                if (checkConnection()) {

                    link_url = pro+url;
                    c1.execute(link_url);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    myText.setText("No Internet Connection");

                }
            } else {
                myText.setText("Unknown domain");
            }

        } else {
            myText.setText("Invalid URL");

        }

    } else {
        myText.setText("URL can\'t empty");
    }
}
```

I have that code to show a web page source. I want to show the result in another activity, but I don't know how. I use the create object from the first activity, but it's not method

```
public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data from a activity , linkUrl is your variable which data you want to pass :

```
Intent intent = new Intent (YourActivity.this, ShowActivity.class) ; 
intent.putExtra("KEY_LINK" , linkUrl);
startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving data from  ShowActivity , Access the data by the key in onCreate():

```
 String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY_LINK");
```

Link : [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Link : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Why you use this kind of things. If you want to load a web page in an activity use `webview` for it. no need two activities to do that. Another way you can create a class which has your `doSomething` method (it should be `public static`) and call it from an `activity` by using that's class object. When you coding don't create unnecessary activities.

Comment: okay sir, thank you for the advice, i will try to work on that, and not create unnecessary activities.